# Show that ${\{s_n}\}$ is bounded if $s_n = b_1r + b_2r^2 + ... + b_nr^n$ and $0 < r < 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Question: Let ${\{b_n}\}$ be a bounded sequence of nonnegative numbers and r be any number such that $0 \leq r < 1$. Define

$s_n = b_1r + b_2r^2 + ... + b_nr^n$  for every index $n$.

Use The Monotone Convergence Theorem to prove that the series ${\{s_n}\}$ converges.

All what I tried: The Monotone Convergence Theorem says that a monotone sequence converges if and only if it is bounded. To show that ${\{s_n}\}$ converges we have to show that it is bounded and monotone. Since ${\{b_n}\}$ be a bounded and each of $b_n$ is a nonnegative number, so

$|b_n|=b_n\leq M\implies |s_n| = |b_1r + b_2r^2 + ... + b_nr^n|=b_1r + b_2r^2 + ... + b_nr^n\leq Mn\dfrac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}.$

If $r=0$ then $s_n=0$ for every index $n$, thus convergent and we are done; also it is bounded and monotone ($s_n\leq s_{n+1}$) for case  $r=0$, as expected.

For case $0 < r < 1$, the difficulty is that $Mn\dfrac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ can't be finite for always, because $M$ and $\dfrac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ are non-zero finite but as $n$ increases there is no guarantee for $Mn\dfrac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ to be finite.

By the way, ${\{s_n}\}$ is monotone since $s_{n+1}\geq s_n$ and it must converge to $sup{\{s_n}\}$, but if it is bounded.

Please help me to show that ${\{s_n}\}$ is bounded so I can complete the proof that ${\{s_n}\}$ converges.

Thank you.

Comment: Where does your $Mn$ come from? That $n$ shouldn't be there. (You have a small mistake apart from that, but that one doesn't matter much.)

Comment: @Daniel Fischer: Would you please guide me how to show that $\dfrac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ is finite for ANY fixed $r$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: We have $0 \leqslant r < 1$. What does that tell you about $r^{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You've just made a simple error. Since $b_n\leq m$, $0\leq b_1r+\ldots+b_nr^n\leq Mr+\ldots+Mr^n$ from which you can take out a common factor. Can you finish it off?

Comment: Yes, I got it! Thank you.

Comment: But, how to show that $\dfrac{r-r^{n+1}}{1-r}$ is also bounded, especially for $r\rightarrow 1$ and $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: You don't take the limit as $r\to 1,$ you just have to show that fraction is some real number for any fixed $0\le r<1$ as you take the limit $n\to\infty.$ It's kind of similar to the concept of seeing that although $m$ is a number for any integer $m,$ the limit as $m\to \infty$  is not a number.